# How to match a logger on a specific sub package name?

Tags: django, logging

In my Django project, I have several apps (say `app_a`, `app_b`, `app_c`).  Each of these apps contains several commands:

```
project
+-app_a
| +-management
|   +-commands
|     +- command_1.py, command_2.py
|
+-app_b
| +-management
|   +-commands
|     +- command_3.py, command_4.py
|
+-app_c
  +-management
    +-commands
      +- command_5.py
```

In my project settings (`settings.py`), I'd like to define a [logger](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) that will intercept all the logs coming from any [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), whatever the app it's located in.  It would spare me to create some 'commands_logger' that I'll have to explicitly call in each of my commands modules.  Something that would look like

```
'*.management.commands': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'handlers': ['console'],
},
```

Is it possible ?  How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a `FileHandler` with a custom `Filter` which only passes through events from specific locations. For example:

```
class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        name = record.name
        return (name.endswith('.management.commands') or
                '.management.commands.' in name)
```

This will only allow through events from management commands. Of course, you could refine this logic as you see fit. The `FileHandler` instance can be attached to the root logger - the filter shouldn't let any extraneous stuff through, so it should be OK to do that.